# PSR-4 autoloading trouble

Tags: php, namespaces, composer-php, autoload, psr-4

I want to load HomeController class from `lib` directory:

```
root/
-lib/
--/HomeController.php
-vendor/
-composer.json
-index.php
```

Composer.json

```
"autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
        "Lib\\": "lib/"
    }
}
```

HomeController.php

```
namespace Lib;
class HomeController {}
```

index.php

```
var_damp(new \Lib\HomeController.php);
```

It doesn't find the class.
But if I put HomeController.php inside Controllers directory:

```
root/
-lib/
--/Controllers/HomeController.php
```

And update the namespaces: index.php to `var_damp(new \Lib\Controllers\HomeController.php);` and HomeController.php to:

```
namespace Lib\Controllers;
class HomeController {}
```

It works perfect.
It's weird, I can't find any docs talking about it. I don't need additional directories, in this case I want the HomeController class directly inside `lib` directory.

How can I make it works inside `lib` folder?

Comment: may be you miss execute `composer dumpautoload` command?

Comment: I tried `composer dump-autoload`, `autoload_psr4.php` is correct. Also I removed composer.lock and rebuild it again. I still can't use autoload.

Answer (score 0):

I think the trailing slash in the path reference is your problem. Change the autoload section in `composer.json` to this:

```
"autoload": {
  "psr-4": {
    "Lib\\": "lib"
  }
}
```

...then run `composer dump-autoload`.

Comment: Tried it a few times. It doesn't have any effect. In Composer docs they advise to use the trailing slash. Anyway I'll try it again. Thanks